# Why is my question opinion-based?

Tags: discussion

My question, [How Commonly Used is the Bradford Factor?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/105896/how-commonly-used-is-the-bradford-factor), was closed for being primarily opinion based (though I think it also got a few votes for being too broad). I can't seem to figure out what is too opinion-based or too broad about it. Although any question about common practice is somewhat opinion-based, there are [a great number](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q="how+common") of questions asking if X is common practice that weren't closed.

Comment: Quickly browing those similar questions you linked I can see most of them are also closed...

Comment: @DarkCygnus When writing this, I hadn’t realized that on the mobile app searching it fails to mark questions as closed until you open them up. I didn’t think any of them were closed until much later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between "Is this common" and "How common is this".

"How common is this?" got the "too broad" closure votes because it's **STILL** too broad.

It could be very common in blue collar work, but not in white collar work, or in certain states, or certain nations, or even certain industries within certain states.

So, yes either opinion based, or too broad fits in this instance.

To elucidate a bit: (from comments) The first, "is this common", asks a simple question, which does not call for a quantifiable answer. you can answer "yes, it is" or "I see it all the time". The latter asks for a quantifiable answer: "It has found penetration in no less than 72% of the workplace". In the former, someone can answer "Yes, I've seen it occasionally" or "Never heard of it", in the latter, again, you're asking for something quantifiable.

Comment: Aside from being subjective, it requires knowledge from more than one individual as well, such as a survey, which is not what we do here.

Comment: If you follow my second link in the question, two of the first four questions that come up all ask “how common is this phenomenon” with no other specificity. Do you think those questions (and many others like them) should be closed? I see that you’re trying to draw a distinction, but I don’t see what the distinction is?

Comment: To be specific, I'm talking about [How common are IQ tests during job interviews?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/79265/how-common-are-iq-tests-during-job-interviews) and [How common is it that salaries are made public?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40131/how-common-is-it-that-salaries-are-made-public)

Comment: [How common is a Scent Free workplace, and how can we clearly define the policy?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/25960/how-common-is-a-scent-free-workplace-and-how-can-we-clearly-define-the-policy) and [Probation period before receiving medical benefits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/62539/probation-period-before-receiving-medical-benefits) also seem like they should be closed, according to what you're endorsing. I have found a half-dozen more but don't want to inundate you with links.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Comment: @gnat I am aware. I’m not saying that my question is okay because of those questions, I’m asking for clarification. I want to know if Snark thinks that all of those questions are inappropriate for the site as well to further my understanding of their answer.

Comment: @StellaBiderman many of those were closed, some were low rated and likely slipped by, some, like the trending of backpacks are clearly observable.  What you asked for is, as Chris E pointed out, is something that would require something akin to a survey.

Comment: @TheSnarkKnight can you explain what you mean by your first line of the answer? I don’t understand it.

Comment: @StellaBiderman the first "is this common", asks a simple question, which does not call for a quantifiable answer.  you can answer "yes, it is" or "I see it all the time".  The latter asks for a quantifiable answer:  "It has found penetration in no less than 72% of the workplace".  In the former, someone can answer "Yes, I've seen it occasionally" or "Never heard of it", in the latter, again, you're asking for something quantifiable.  Does that help?

Comment: @TheSnarkKnight Yes, thank you.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I updated my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We can not answer how common it is because how "common" something is is a bad subjective question.  This is because common is a very relative term.  If a major employer in the area uses the formula there is a good chance that other employers in the area emulate that because its already something that a good portion of the population understands.

I have edited the question to ask for specific examples of major companies that make use of the formula and how it is implemented in their policies.  I think this will help get you the information you are looking for.